# Creating Files Echo Success or Fail

Tags: powershell, logging, append

I can't figure our where to properly add `If (!){} else{}` in my code when I create a new file. I want it to append to a .log file "Log Created" when true and "Log failed" when false. Am I approaching this wrong?

```
$foo = c:\path\to\folder
$bar_bar = <variable>

New-Item -path "$foo" -name "$bar_bar-test_archive.log" -type "file" -value "`n`r$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss) : Process started.`n"
```

SIDENOTE: I have to name my file `"$bar_bar-test_archive.log"` but I would prefer to name it `"$bar_bar_test_archive.log"`, however because of the underscore in the variable name adding and underscore between the variable and constant messes it up. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SIDENOTE: I have to name my file "$bar_bar-test_archive.log" but I
>   would prefer to name it "$bar_bar_test_archive.log", however because
>   of the underscore in the variable name adding and underscore between
>   the variable and constant messes it up. Is there a way to do this?

You can resolve that either of these ways:

```
-name "$bar_bar`_test_archive.log"

-name "$($bar_bar)_test_archive.log"
```

As for logging if it works vs if it doesn't the correct way is with a try/catch construct which is a way to capture errors. For example,

```
$LogFile = 'C:\PSTest\log.log'

try
{
    Some-Action
}
catch
{
    'Failed to run Some-Action' | Out-File $LogFile -Append
}
```

Inside the catch you would also generally add a Break or Continue for something like this:

```
$LogFile = 'C:\PSTest\log.log'

try
{
    Some-Action
}
catch
{
    'Failed to run Some-Action' | Out-File $LogFile -Append
    break # Exit Script
}

'Successfully ran Some-Action' | Out-File $LogFile -Append  # The script will only get here if there's no error as an error will trigger the break.
```

You end up with something like this:

```
$foo = 'c:\PSTest'
$bar_bar = 'Test'
$LogFile = 'C:\PSTest\log.log'

try
{
    New-Item -path "$foo" -name "$bar_bar`_test_archive.log" -type "file" -value "`n`r$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss) : Process started.`n" -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
    "$(Get-Date -Format G) - Log Failed" | Out-File $LogFile -Append
    break 
}

"$(Get-Date -Format G) - Log Succeeded" | Out-File $LogFile -Append
```

Some additional notes:

- Use more descriptive variable names than "Foo" and "Bar." It makes the code more readable and the longer your scripts get the easier it is to forget what a variable contains when named poorly.
- You are/were missing quotes around the values for your variables. As strings use ''
- You'll notice I added `-ErrorAction Stop` to the New-Item command; that allows the catch to function properly.

Comment: Question: is "-Format G" a kind of back-reference function to the previously defined format, or are you just shortcutting..?

Comment: @physlexic shotcutting. G is 8/30/2007 11:20:24 AM which isn't exactly what you had in the OP but it's close.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't want to use a `try`/`catch` like omniomi is using, which would likely be more appropriate, you could use `Test-Path`:

```
$foo = c:\path\to\folder
$bar_bar = <variable>

New-Item -path "$foo" -name "$bar_bar-test_archive.log" -type "file" -value "`n`r$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss) : Process started.`n"
If (!(Test-Path $foo)){} else{}
```

Answer to SideNote:
You could use `$()` to evaluate inside the quotes like this: `"$($bar)_bar_test_archive.log"`